# Convert 2D array into object array

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, multidimensional-array

I've got a 2D array and I need to convert each "line" of the array into a separate object array element that contains a String, an Int and multiple Doubles. Right now each 2D array element is stored as a String.

Here is my class object:

```
public Object() {
    String = "null";
    Double1 = -1.0;
    Double2 = -1.0;
    Double3 = -1.0;
    Integer = -1; 
}
```

Here is my method used to convert the 2D array to a class array:

```
 public static void objectConvert() {
        Object[] objArray = new Object[count];
        for (int i = 0; i<count; i++) {
            objArray[i] = new Object(data[i][0], Double.parseDouble(data[i][1]), Double.parseDouble(data[i][2]), Double.parseDouble(data[i][3]), Integer.parseInt(data[i][4]));
        }
        System.out.println(objArray[0]);
        System.out.println(objArray[1]);
    }
```

Here are the error that I get when compiling:

```
 javac Program.java

Program.java:42: error: constructor Object in class Object cannot be applied to given types;
                        Object[i] = new Object(data[i][0],
 Double.parseDouble(data[i][1]), Double.parseDouble(data[i][2]), Double.parseDouble(data[i][3]), Integer.parseInt(data[i][4]));
                                               ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String,double,double,double,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Comment: Don't define a class named `Object` or any other predefined class. You will end up confusing yourself and other programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `objArray[i]` in place of `Object[i]` while assigning inside the `for` loop.

There is one more error, you haven't defined a constructor which takes `String,double,double,double,int` and consider renaming your class from `Object` to something else.

Your constructor can be like this:

```
public Object(String a, Double b, Double c, Double d, Integer e) {
    string = a;
    double1 = b;
    double2 = b;
    double3 = d;
    integer = e; 
}
```

Comment: @user3264252 I guess you are new to java, please follow **camel case** while naming your variables.

Comment: I changed it to Object just to make it easier to understand as my actual variables are named confusingly to an outsider

Answer (score 0):

> Object[i] = new Object(data[i][0], Double.parseDouble(data[i][1]), Double.parseDouble(data[i][2]),
>   Double.parseDouble(data[i][3]), Integer.parseInt(data[i][4]));

its

```
objArray[i]=  new Object(data[i][0], Double.parseDouble(data[i][1]), Double.parseDouble(data[i][2]), Double.parseDouble(data[i][3]), Integer.parseInt(data[i][4]));
```

> Your class Object must have a constructor that have reads 5 parameter
>   (String, double, double, double, Integer)

Comment: Ooh thank you, that fixed that mistake, but I'm still getting the other error:

Program.java:42: error: constructor Object in class Object cannot be applied to given types;
                        Object[i] = new Object(data[i][0],
 Double.parseDouble(data[i][1]), Double.parseDouble(data[i][2]), Double.parseDouble(data[i][3]), Integer.parseInt(data[i][4]));
                                               ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String,double,double,double,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: possibly because of the absence of the constructor.